# Get an id of active tab in materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I know how to select / activate (programmatically) a tab in materializecss using jquery(as mentioned in documentation):

```
$('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
```

But how to get an id of an active(selected) tab in materializecss using javascript or jquery when I click a button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the active class to get the current active tab. And hence can get the id of the current tab. Below is a demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  });
$('#getID').click(function(){
  console.log("Active Tab:"+$(".active").attr('id'));
  console.log("Active Tab Div:"+$(".active").attr('href'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1" id="1test">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2" id="2test">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4" id="4test">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>
  
  <button id="getID">
  GetID
  </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although above techniques might be ok there is official way to do it in materializecss.:

```
  $('ul.tabs').tabs({
    onShow: onShow,//Function to be called on tab Show event
    swipeable: false,
    responsiveThreshold: Infinity // breakpoint for swipeable
  });

    function onShow(tabOBJ){
        console.log(tabOBJ.selector);
    }
```

I hope this might help you and others.

Comment: The show event will not be called when clicking on a button though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery. As the active tab will has the class `active` you can use it for getting the tab id.

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
           alert($(".active").attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

A working fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/UTux2/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("ul.tabs > li > a").click(function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;});
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', hash);
```

make hash id first then place that in place `tab_id`